# Can I assign a just inserted ManagedObject to self?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have the following factory method. I'm just wondering if the assignment

```
self = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName 
inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

is correct, given the fact that my class is a subclass of NSManagedObject

thanks

```
+ (CBItem *)insertEntityForName:(NSString*)entityName fromXMLElement:(NSXMLElement*)xmlElement withQueryType:(CBSearchQueryType)queryType inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)inContext

...

self = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName 
inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

... 

return self;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not correct. You only assign to `self` inside an `init` method. For a factory type method, you should be returning a variable, e.g.

```
CBItem* newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

//Other stuff

return newItem;
```

Comment: OK. What if the factory method is invoked by a subclass of CBItem ? Should I use a cast ? (CBSubClassItem = [CBSubClassItem insertEntityForName:entityName fromXMLElement:xmlElement]; )

Comment: Well, the returned class depends on the entity name anyway, you could use `id` all the way through and only assign to a variable of the correct type from your original calling function? It's hard to say without knowing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, I'me returning the superclass, and it works. I'm a bit surprise: I'm returning a class and I'm assigning the returned value to a subclass.

Comment: insertNewObjectEtc returns an instance of your subclass. Then you assign it to a variable of your base class and return it as the type of your base class too. Then you assign it to a variable of the subclass. So from start to finish the instance has been of the subclass, it's just been in a more generic variable. Objective C is pretty lax about allowing casts to a more specific type.

Comment: @morningstar I see! insertNewObjectEtc is returning my class, that's why. I guess if I had initialized the base class with alloc] init] an returned it, the compiler would have complained.

Comment: InsertNewObject is the way to make new managed objects, don't use alloc/init.  Good discussion here, thanks both!

Comment: You can use alloc] init] to make managed objects; it will work too. Actually the init method you use is `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`. It works by using an Objective C trick. Unlike languages like C++ and Java, in Objective C a constructor is allowed to change the class of an object! initEtc actually returns a different object than you alloc'ed.

Comment: My point was, you don't do [[object alloc] init] - this is specifically prohibited in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

self in a class method (declared with + instead of -) refers to the class object. Though, once within any method, self is like a local variable. You can reassign it to anything you want, as long as you don't expect it to continue to act like self is normally supposed to. So what you were doing will not be broken, though it is potentially confusing.